# operator || cannot be applied to int and bool

Tags: c#

```
class coding
{
    int a;
    public int setdata(int feet,int inches)
    {
        if (feet || inches < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid");

        }
        a = 12 * feet + inches;

        else { return a; }

    }
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the inches is" + a);
    }
}
```

I am having an problem at this line:

```
if (feet || inches < 0)
```

I am not getting why this issue is.

Comment: You need to split the comparisons: `if (feet < 0 || inches < 0)`. This way, both sides of the `||` are booleans.

Comment: Also, you can't just have an `else` clause on it's own - it has to come straight after the `if` clause.

Comment: I doubt if there is any language where `(feet || inches <0)` is translated to `either feet or inches are negative`. Most languages would interpret such an operation as a bitwise OR

Comment: And *please* follow [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff926074.aspx) - it makes it much easier to share code, or ask questions on Stack Overflow if you are using consistent conventions as every other C# programmer.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have `feet == 3` and `inches == -1`? I.e. "three feet *without* an inch"

Comment: BTW the fastest way to solve and avoid such problems is to find a book or course and learn C#. Writing a conditional statement is the most fundamental concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the numbers were different:

> "I want to enter this `if` statement when `feet` has a value smaller than `X`, or `inches` has a value smaller than `Y`".

The `if` would then be:

```
if (feet < X || inches < Y)
{
    // condition met
}
```

The same syntax applies for all values of `X` and `Y`. Now, set `X` to `0` and `Y` to `0`.

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote the answer if it helped you, or mark it as accepted if it answers your question. You should do this for all answers you found useful.

Comment: ohh .. i am a new user of this stack overflow. thats why

Answer (score 5):

If statement expects boolean expression so you need to write when the condition of your int value is invalid. You can redesign your code like this:

```
public int setdata(int feet,int inches)
{
    if(feet < 0 || inches < 0)
    {   
        return -1;
    }

     return 12 * feet + inches;
}
```

After that when you call setdata method

```
int result = setdata(feet, inches);
if(result == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Your input for inches:{inches} or feet:{feet} is invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this line :

```
if (feet || inches < 0)
```

is a very "natural language approach". It would be really nice if you could just code as you speak but the compiler language demands each case to be specified in detail.

On each side of the `||` operator the compiler expects a `bool` variable. So it is confused. You have to explicitly state each case:

```
if (feet < 0 || inches < 0)
```

the return result of this comparison (`feet < 0`) is of type `bool`

Answer (score 0):

For any Boolean expression, you have to write the expression twice;each time you make a decision explicitly so that the compiler knows exactly what to do:

```
if (feet < 0 || inches < 0)
```

Same goes with `&&` :

```
if (feet < 0 && inches < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The || operator checks for atleast any one of the operands on either side of it is ture. Here you have two integers at both the sides of || operator which will throw an error. So it should be like

```
if(feet < 0 || inches < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to set, say

```
 myData.setdata(3, -1);
```

which means "three feet *without* an inch"? If it's the case

```
public int setdata(int feet,int inches) {
  // compute length
  int value = 12 * feet + inches;

  // if the length is invalid, throw the exception
  if (value < 0) {
    if (feet < 0) 
      throw ArgumentOutOfRangeExample("feet");
    else    
      throw ArgumentOutOfRangeExample("inches");
  }

  a = value; 

  return value;
}
```

Or (if you don't want to have exceptions thrown)

```
public int setdata(int feet,int inches) {
  // compute length
  int value = 12 * feet + inches;

  // if the length is valid, assign it to a
  if (value >= 0) 
    a = value;
  else
    Console.WriteLine("invalid");

  return a;
}
```

Comment: second answer is more worthy.